# Probability for Communication Networks

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1. A computer communication channel transmits words of $n$ bits using an error-correcting code which is
   capable of correcting errors in up to $k$ bits. Here each bit is either a $0$ or a $1$. Assume each bit is
   transmitted correctly with probability $p$ and incorrectly with probability $q$ independently of all other
   bits.

(a) Find a formula for the probability that a word is correctly transmitted.

(b) Calculate the probability of correct transmission for $n = 8$, $k = 2$, and $p = 0:01$.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) calculation. The probability that $k$ or fewer bits are transmitted incorrectly is
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}q^ip^{n-i}.$$

**Remark:** In the formula, I have used your assertion that the probability that a bit is transmitted incorrectly is called $q$. There may be a typo in the question, since in the concrete example you use $p=0.01$, meaning that the probability $q=1-p$ that a bit is transmitted **incorrectly** is $0.99$. If there is such a high probability of incorrect transmission of a bit, we would be much better off *reversing* the bit received!

If there really is a typo, and the probability of *incorrect* transmission is $p$, then in the formula above, just interchange $q$ and $p$.